# My normal maps are coming out all blue and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: normal-map

I have been jumping from tutorial to tutorial trying to figure out how to bake my normal map for my creature and its killing me. all my normal maps come out like this. any help would be awesome.  [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/